# application(:didFinishLaunchingwithOptions:) does not get called if apps is killed and opened immediately

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I have noticed that if I kill the app from the multitasking view and open it immediately `application(:didFinishLaunchingwithOptions:)` lifecycle method is not called but the sceneDelegate's `scene(:willConnectTo:)` method is called.

As far as I know, the above implies the app is not deinitialised and still in memory even after killing and reopening the app.

And because of the above behaviour the `NSPersistentContainer` object is still in memory and my Core Data stack setup code is present in `scene(:willConnectTo:)`, so it's again initialised and it causes a crash with the following error :

```
Failed to load the Persistent Store due to: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134081 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice})
```

Here is my Core Data Stack setup:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        // Show splash screen
        let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "AppLoading", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AppLoadingViewController")
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        
        CoreDataManager.shared.setup {
            // Always present the UI from a Main Thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if AppSettings.shared.onboardingFinished {
                    self.presentHomeUI(using: window)
                } else {
                    self.presentOnboardingUI(using: window)
                }
            }
        }

         self.window = window
         window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Is this normal behaviour of `application(:didFinishLaunchingwithOptions:)` not called when app is killed an opened immediately ? another mystery is that this issue only affects iPhone X and above at least according to our crash logs.

If the above behaviour cannot be avoided then which method should be an ideal place for Core Data Setup ?

Here is a video of the crash that I am able to reproduce on a device:
https://file.re/2021/05/07/sampleprojectappcrashvideo/

And here is a sample project that I created which demonstrate the crash:
https://github.com/nik6018/CrashDemo (can only reproduce crash on iPhone X and above)

Answer (score 1):

So I filled a DTS for the above issue with Apple as nothing on the internet helped me in understanding this issue.

So here's what Apple said:

- Whenever the app is swiped away from the multitasking menu, the iOS disconnects and releases the scene.
- If the app doesn't has anymore scenes, iOS kills the app from memory
- But iOS doesn't do the above step immediately, so if I open the app quickly again it just creates a new scene and attaches it to the existing app instance
- And since my Core Data setup is in the `scene(:willConnectTo:)` method the app crash as I am trying to initialise the store again even though an existing store is already present in memory.

To resolve this issue I have 2 choices:

1. Move my Core Data Setup in App Delegate
2. Deinit my Core Data Manager when the app calls `sceneDidDisconnect(_:)`

I went with option 2. and everything works as expected.

Honestly if I had watched the WWDC19 videos I wouldn't had to waste my DTS ticket :(

Hope this helps anyone if they come across this behaviour.